# SQL: Add number of unique values in a group

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table such as:

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020/4/4 | 1 | a |
| 2020/4/4 | 1 | a |
| 2020/4/4 | 1 | b |
| 2020/4/4 | 2 | t |
| 2020/4/4 | 2 | u |
| 2020/5/4 | 3 | u |

I want to find out how many IDs have more than one unique value at a particular date.
So this is what I should get for the table from above:

- 2020/4/4: 1 (=> only ID=1 has more than one unique value (a+b))
- 2020/4/5: 0

I tried to get it with:

```
SELECT date, SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT value)>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table
GROUP BY date, id
```

But it did not work. How do I do it right?

Comment: Which database are you using?  MySQL5.x has different syntax and functionality from MySQL8, or SQL Server, or Oracle, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some databases will let you count "tuples", allowing this...

```
SELECT
  date,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT (id, value)) > COUNT(*) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  date
```

Otherwise your style of approach works, but you need to aggregate twice using sub-queries.

```
SELECT date, MAX(has_duplicate_values)
FROM
(
  SELECT date, id, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT value) > COUNT(*) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END has_duplicate_values
  FROM table
  GROUP BY date, id
)
  AS date_id_aggregate
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your request as following:

```
SELECT date, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT value)>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM `table` GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find out how many IDs have more than one unique value at a particular date.

You can aggregate twice:

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN num > num_distinct_values THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_ids_with_duplicates
FROM (SELECT date, id, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT value) as num_distinct_values,
             COUNT(*) as num
      FROM table
      GROUP BY date, id
     ) di
GROUP BY date;
```